# WebBroser1.Navigate works only once (C#) (reloading webbrowser)

Tags: c#, browser

I have form with web browser component, there is a button which triggers page reload, here is the code:

```
kiekmiestu = comboBox1.Text;
string nuoroda = "http://centrosokoladine.lt/PHP/generatorius.php?m=" + kiekmiestu;
webBrowser1.Navigate(nuoroda);
```

Lets say kiemiestu gets teks four, so the php generator generates 4 citys in random places of the map in each page refresh, my problem is that when I click the button second time WebBrowser1 seems nots navigating second time, couse page doesn't change. Maybe it's cache problems, o WebBrowser doesn't navigate to same page if it's already showed?

Comment: You should worck on your acception rate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try **webbrowser.refresh()**
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txewax99.aspx):

```
private void refreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Skip refresh if about:blank is loaded to avoid removing
    // content specified by the DocumentText property.
    if (!webBrowser1.Url.Equals("about:blank"))
    {
        webBrowser1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

**More about webbrowser.Refresh() and why navigate does not work:**

> The WebBrowser control stores Web pages from recently visited sites in
>   a cache on the local hard disk. Each page can specify an expiration
>   date indicating how long it will remain in the cache. When the control
>   navigates to a page, it saves time by displaying a cached version, if
>   one is available, rather than downloading the page again. The Refresh
>   method forces the WebBrowser control to reload the current page by
>   downloading it, ensuring that the control displays the latest version.

for clearing the wbbrowser controls cache consider this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326201/de

Comment: Thanks, added refresh funkction after navigate and it works fine now :) P.s. sorry for my tragical gramma.

Comment: I'm here in stackoverflow after some time and as I remember, last time I didin't notice such rate :) Is it something like ratio between questions given and aswered?

Comment: @Tautvydas no if you  post a question and get a correct answer you can mark this question as your answer (under the up/down vote). It is very helpful for other users not to try/read all the given answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
webBrowser1.Refresh();
```